# How to set the Header on Silverlight 3 accordion using data binding

Tags: silverlight, accordion

I can't set the header on a silverlight 3.

I used this code, but every item has the same header "My accordion"

```
<layoutToolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="My Accordion" />
```

I need each header to have a different heading.

I can't use accordion item's header property since I have datagrids as items in the accordion

could anyone  please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<layoutToolkit:AccordionItem>
    <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="My Accordion Header" />
        </StackPanel>    
       </DataTemplate>
    </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.Content>
        <StackPanel>
              ... your data grid
        </StackPanel>
    </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem.Content>
</layoutToolkit:AccordionItem>
```